# Is search onkeyup too unefficient?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onkeyup

I have this form where an admin searches a list of players, and I made it so while he's searching , onkeyup a php script is ran searching for %string% of what he types. Something like google.

I wonder if this is bad if the admin fastly types a name. Or if it can be abused to "flood" the server. I'm on a shared server and I can have a maximum of 15 processes running.

If so, what's the best approach on fixing this? I thought about adding a 1 second limiter between searches. Any other ideas?

```
function getusers()
{
    var whou = ($("#who").val());
    
    $("#theadmins").load("searchusers.php", {who : whou});
}

<input id=\"who\" onkeyup=\"getusers()\" class=\"\" type=\"text\"  placeholder=\"username\" width=\"100\" maxlength=\"32\" size=\"32\" />
```

**Edit**:: It has been a long time, but some are still stumbling upon this question. Today, I would recommend using `debounce` which is available in jQuery, lodash and most modern JS frameworks via RXJS.

Comment: you need to add timeout for server request, so it will start making request only after 300 ms after user is not pressing anything

Comment: I thought about making a bool, setting it to 1 when something is searched, then making a js setTimeout that sets the bool to 0 in xxx ms. Before loading the page, check the bool. Is this the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

I have also applied auto-suggest in a application, with throttling function by **remy sharp**.

```
// https://remysharp.com/2010/07/21/throttling-function-calls
function debounce(fn, delay) {
    var timer = null;
    return function () {
       var context = this, args = arguments;
       clearTimeout(timer);
       timer = setTimeout(function () {
          fn.apply(context, args);
       }, delay);
    };
}
```

And this is how i applied with on keyup, the ajax request will fire after **500(miliseconds)**, but in case if still previews request found then with use of abort the previous request, as you can see below:

```
$('#search').keyup( debounce(function() {
    var currentRequest = null;
    var _q = $.trim( $(this).val() );

    // Only fire if value found in search box
    if( _q.length > 0 ) {
       currentRequest = $.ajax({
           url: '', 
           beforeSend: function() {
               // If found previous ajax request then kill and start new one
               if( currentRequest != null ) {
                   currentRequest.abort();
               }
           }, 
           dataType: 'json'
        });
    }
}, 500) );
```

Answer (score 1):

use keyup:

```
Use keyup():

     $(function () {
    var minlength = 3;

    $("#sample_search").keyup(function () {
        var that = this,
        value = $(this).val();

        if (value.length >= minlength ) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "sample.php",
                data: {
                    'search_keyword' : value
                },
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(msg){
                    //we need to check if the value is the same
                    if (value==$(that).val()) {
                    //Receiving the result of search here
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: the same situation occure after 3 characters!

Comment: can u elaborate it little bit more . I'm not getting what do meany by 3 char

Comment: You set minimum character lenth to check 3 `minlength = 3`, now lets say i want to search `republic days`, after `rep` ajax start firing the requests untill user not stop typing, let say a user type `republic` then you are sending 5 times request to server for same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making too many requests to the server as the user types. You can use `setTimeout` as one option to limit the number of server calls.

But there is possibility that even before the server returns you response for previous request you may be firing multiple server requests if the setTimeout limit is too low.

I would suggest to use a flag as well in the keyup event handler. Once the first server call is fired using setTimeout, wait for the response from the server and set the reset the flag. So based on this the number of server requests can be limited.

Another approach is, as the first keyup event is fired. Set around 1s of delay in setTimeout to get better results.

In case you are about to fetch country list or somethign which depends on the starting letter of the search keyword. In that case, i would prefer caching the data in the client after first request. (If the number of results are less). In subsequent requests will filter the cached data in the client and show.